# How to change a page title of an outer frame that is a different domain?

Tags: javascript, iframe

How can I change the page title of an outer frame that is a different domain?

My code exists inside an iframe on a different domain than the page.

All attempts with `parent.document.title` do not work because of the same-origin policy.

```
|page title         x |
|---------------------|
| domain a.com        |
|                     |
|  |---------------|  | 
|  | iframe        |  |
|  | domain b.com  |  |
|  | my code here  |  |
|  |               |  |
|  -----------------  |
|                     |
-----------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, it's impossible -- preventing this sort of things if the very goal of the same-origin policy, as you mentioned.

Unless a good hacker among us finds a back-door of course :)

**EDIT** If you control the code on domain a.com, the code on b.com could upload the title to a server polled by the code on a.com... but it looks a little bit ugly.